# display result along with user info in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I written a script which reads 2 files in a for loop and calls utility script. At the end, script will call the consolidated report function to display the output in tabular format.

my problem is  am not able to figure out how to display the results along with the user details one after the another. Any help is most appreciated.

```
  function runClients {

if [ ! -f $RFILE ]; then
    echo -e "rfile doesn't exits.. pls check!! exiting"
    exit 1
fi
for t in ` cat $TFILE ` ; do
  for r in ` cat $RFILE ` ; do
  echo "Running client for token: ${t} on item: {$r}" | tee -a $RESULT_FILE
  ${TESTCLIENT} -f $r -u $t ${TEST_LOG_DIR}/${r}_`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.xml >> $RESULT_FILE
   if [ -s $RESULT_FILE ]; then
      STATUS=${STATUS_OK}
     else
      STATUS=${STATUS_NOK}
   fi
  done
 done
 consolidated_report
 sleep $SLEEPTIME # Assuming it needs at least 30 seconds for test client to complete

}
```

consolidated_report function :

```
    function consolidated_report () {
  printf "|===========================================================================|\n";
  printf "Displaying SummaryReport\n"
  echo "Executed on Date : " `date  "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"`
if [[ -r $RESULT_FILE && -s $RESULT_FILE  ]]; then
  printf "|==========================================================================|\n"; 
  printf "|              Round Trip Summary                                          |\n"
  printf "|==========================================================================|\n";
  cat $RESULT_FILE
  echo -e "Testcase status :\e[1;32m ${STATUS_OK}\e[0m                                                    "
  printf "|===========================================================================|\n";

fi
}
```

Currently am getting output like this :

```
    Running testclient for user: AQIC5wM2LY4SfcxZae% on item: {ffed}
Running testclient for user: Q3MTkxMDkwOQACUzEAAjA2%23 on item: {rrcw}
|===========================================================================|
Displaying SummaryReport
Executed on Date :  02/17/16 09:39:59
|==========================================================================|
|              Round Trip Summary                                          |
|==========================================================================|
Number of Connection Count = 1
Items Requested: 2 Item Retrieval Time: 86 milliseconds.
Average Round Trip : 65 milliseconds
Minimum Round Trip : 44 milliseconds for item: ffed
Maximum Round Trip : 86 milliseconds for item: rrcw
Item retrieval complete. Exiting.
Channel: 1 Disconnected application from server.
Peak Rate: 0.00 Peak Average Update Size: 0
Number of Connection Count = 1
Items Requested: 2 Item Retrieval Time: 83 milliseconds.
Average Round Trip : 62 milliseconds
Minimum Round Trip : 42 milliseconds for item: ffed
Maximum Round Trip : 83 milliseconds for item: rrcw
Item retrieval complete. Exiting.
Channel: 1 Disconnected application from server.
Peak Rate: 0.00 Peak Average Update Size: 0
Testcase status : Passed
|===========================================================================|
```

I was expecting to get the summary report as :

```
    |===========================================================================|
Displaying SummaryReport
Executed on Date :  02/17/16 09:39:59
|==========================================================================|
|              Round Trip Summary                                          |
|==========================================================================|
Running testclient for user: AQIC5wM2LY4SfcxZae% on item: {ffed}
Number of Connection Count = 1
Items Requested: 2 Item Retrieval Time: 86 milliseconds.
Average Round Trip : 65 milliseconds
Minimum Round Trip : 44 milliseconds for item: ffed
Maximum Round Trip : 86 milliseconds for item: rrcw
Item retrieval complete. Exiting.
Channel: 1 Disconnected application from server.
Peak Rate: 0.00 Peak Average Update Size: 0
Running testclient for user: Q3MTkxMDkwOQACUzEAAjA2%23 on item: {rrcw}
Number of Connection Count = 1
Items Requested: 2 Item Retrieval Time: 83 milliseconds.
Average Round Trip : 62 milliseconds
Minimum Round Trip : 42 milliseconds for item: ffed
Maximum Round Trip : 83 milliseconds for item: rrcw
Item retrieval complete. Exiting.
Channel: 1 Disconnected application from server.
Peak Rate: 0.00 Peak Average Update Size: 0
Testcase status : Passed
|===========================================================================|
```

Comment: Add `set -x` near the start and you should be able to figure out where the extra line comes from.

Comment: Try to replace your _| tee -a_ with a _>>_ in your double loop.

Comment: It looks like the response output is copied to $RESULT_FILE after some delay from ${TESTCLIENT}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there will always be some delay after each call, you can distribute the output of individual calls into separate output files, afterwards you can unite them with another small code;

```
for t in ` cat $TFILE ` ; do
  for r in ` cat $RFILE ` ; do
    touch $RESULT_FILE.$t.$r
    echo "Running client for token: ${t} on item: {$r}" | tee -a $RESULT_FILE.$t.$r
    ${TESTCLIENT} -f $r -u $t ${TEST_LOG_DIR}/${r}_`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.xml >> $RESULT_FILE.$t.$r
    if [ -s $RESULT_FILE ]; then
      STATUS=${STATUS_OK}
    else
      STATUS=${STATUS_NOK}
    fi
  done
done
```

So for the first call from your example, you will have a output file with name;
`$RESULT_FILE.AQIC5wM2LY4SfcxZae%.{ffed}`, and it will contain first the small echo, then the output of the client call. Afterwards you can concatenate these files into `$RESULT_FILE`, and call `consolidated_report`

Or you can just have a index and increment for each call for a (much) less messier file names; `$RESULT_FILE$i`

Though the messy file names does not matter, since those will be just temp files.

Comment: I have quick query to ask : I my output am getting 3 times results been displayed even though I have one user and 2 data file.. am just confused.. could you be able to help me out on this.

Comment: That is weird, try to keep the temp files after script ends, are there 2 or 3 of them? Also check their contents too.